# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound volume and push notification sound volume is different

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, system-sounds

Case 1: Let's say i set my ringer volume to 4.

When i play my .m4r file in app using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound, sound is **low** than when i get push notification for same .m4r file at same ringer volume.

Case 2: I set my ringer volume full

Now, When i play my .m4r file in app using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound, sound is **little louder** than when i get push notification for same .m4r file at same ringer volume.

Note: I have my own example.m4r file to play.

Please Help !!

Comment: Following this. I think this is an issue that Apple needs to look into, though. I have the same issue. System sounds from `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` are definitely not loud enough. Even with the volume all the way up.